# Xamarin - SharpCifs connectivity issues

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the SharpCifs nuget package to upload a file to my network drive in Xamarin, but I'm having some connectivity issues while trying to connect to the server.

the line that I think is giving me troubles is this:

```
var file = new SmbFile("smb://UserName:Password@ServerIP/ShareName/Folder/NewFileName.txt");
```

my username contains an @ symbol in it, and when I put the @ symbol in the username, the smb link goes from blue to orange, changing to a string. I then get the error:

```
"invalid url: invalid port number specified".
```

I believe this is because of the @ symbol in my username.

Do I need to format this code differently so that my username is read correctly? How can this be done?

Comment: How about url encoding it: `@` = `%40`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. I'm starting to think it's because my username and password are literally wrong (not sure how) I'm going to ask around at work to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had to do with the fact that I didn't add the domain name to my network shares login. After adding the domain name, I was able to place my files into my network drive.

I ended up changing my code to this:

```
var auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("DomainName","username","password");

string path = "Ip/file/path/";
var file = new SmbFile(path, auth);

...
```